# Turning map into plain object for TS declaration

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have this:

```
let cachedPromises: Map<string, Promise<any>> = new Map();
```

what is the equivalent declaration for a plain object?

Something like this:

```
interface IMyMap {
  [key: string]: Promise<any>
}

let cachedPromises: IMyMap = {};
```

is that sufficient?

Comment: yep, it seems sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sufficient, but it does come as a double edged sword in that you can't implement the interface on a class that has any property that does not return a Promise:

```
class Person implements IMyMap {
    [key: string]: Promise<any>
    constructor(private firstName) { // Error: Property 'firstName' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type 'Promise<any>'.
    }
}
```